# Content-disposition: attachment does not force download as attachment

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers

As the title suggests, despite setting the content-disposition header to attachment, and seeing the binary data successfully returned from the server, it simply will not trigger the download.

The files are stored as a BLOB in a mysql database and my browser is Chrome 55.

My code:

```
$doc = $database->getDocument($docId);

$filename = $doc['name'];
$filetype = $doc['type'];
$filecontent = $doc['content'];

header('Content-Type: ' . $filetype);
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($filecontent));
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . '"' . $filename . '"');
echo $filecontent;
```

[image: response headers]

[image: preview]

I've tried changing the Content-type to 'application/octet-stream' as well as changing the Content-disposition from 'attachment' to 'download' with no luck.

I have no idea what the problem is and I would appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: How are you triggering the request?

Comment: jQuery post request

Comment: So did you try to access that page directly in browser?

Comment: I don't understand. The page is clearly responding when I make the request.

Comment: Hi @Shaffanhoon have you found the any solution for this!! I am in a similar situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364318/how-to-enforce-the-webpagejsp-to-download-the-content-on-ajax-success